# Angular directive not recognizing scope of controller

Tags: angularjs

First of all I know I am going to have to change the title, hopefully I can better form my question based on the answers.

I am working on a [breadcrumb using angular](http://plnkr.co/edit/C7r0BoXTC06PwFeuwyFa?p=preview) (let me know if the link fails) but for some reason it isn't working as I would expect. Everything seems fine but when I click the link to go to the next page (sorry in advance for the annoying alert). I get the following error...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addCrumbs' of undefined

The directive is clearly working so I am guessing it is this line that is causing the issue...

```
angular.element('#crumb').scope().addCrumbs(crumbs);
```

Can someone explain why this is not working?

Comment: I am guessing a bit; but it appears in the second index2.html you are accessing the '#crumb' before it is created.  Such code may be better put in a controller?

Comment: So in that case how would I load it differently for each page?

Comment: How would you load what differently for each page?  I would only use AngularJS to build a single page application; not a multi-page web site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why you'r doing it wrong :)

- First of all, Angular is designed for **single page applications** and can simulate navigation between pages through modules like [ngRoute (official)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [ui-router (from Angular UI Team, more powerful, more complicated)](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).
- Your example doesn't follow the "Angular way" cause you have two "index" page, I mean, Angular (and your app) is re-loaded each time you click on an internal link so you can't share variables between pages (in your case you want a "breadcrumb" shared between pages).
- Your `breadcrumb` directive should share the `breadcrumb` array via [data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) instead of using an external controller explicitly. [See here for more infos](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings).
- The `ng-repeat` directive should be applied to the `li` element instead of the `ol` element.

#### Updated Plunkr

See the <kbd>[**updated version of your Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/1gaJHDzMyf80an34VweG?p=preview)</kbd>.
I added ngRoute module and separated pages. **BUT** I think it's not a very reusable and clean way for breadcrumbs.

#### Conclusion

I recommend you to use a dedicated module to handle your breadcrumb, like [ng-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-breadcrumbs) (see the <kbd>[demo here](http://ianwalter.github.io/ng-breadcrumbs/#/)</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks I think it will take me a bit to get through all of this. I agree with pretty much all that you have said, however, the ngRoute stuff my be a little tough since I am trying to integrate with an existing design. So I was shying away from it at first. I will try to give it another chance and see where I end up. I appreciate your response!